# Set delay on submit button; i.d. button grey and disabled for x seconds after click

Tags: javascript, button, submit, delay

I like to set a delay on a submit button. In other words greyed out for some seconds after clicking that button. How can I accomplish this with js?

Comment: So you want to disable the button for a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/jhNcM/

```
<input type="button" id="aaa" value="button" />

$('#aaa').click(function() {
    var aaa =  $(this);
    aaa.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        aaa.prop('disabled', false);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Plain JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/R5p5q/1/

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>
```

​

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
    var elemSubmit = document.getElementById('mySubmit');
    elemSubmit.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

    // Removes disabling after 3 seconds
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        elemSubmit.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }, 3e3);
},false);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that http://jsfiddle.net/Ktk6f/

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="submitData" id="myButton" />
```

JS

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.attr('disabled', true);
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        that.attr('disabled', false);
    }, 1000);
});
```

It requires jQuery JS framework

Comment: @Kessi: It is better to use prop instead of attr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    if (this.disabled) {
        return;
    }
    this.disabled = true;
    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        this.disabled = false;
    }, this), 3000);
});
```

Comment: If you already use jQuery (for proxy), why not to use the $().prop() method??

Comment: @Naor because it's shorter and doesn't use strings: `this.disabled = true` vs `$(this).prop( "disabled", true )`